# How to enable/disable a textbox with a button

Tags: c#, textbox, isenabled

I looked everywhere for this and didnt find a solution.

**All I want is that when I click the button, the textbox becomes enabled, so we can write in it.**

I tried :

```
public void button11_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

     textbox11.Enabled = true; 

    }
```

and this is the xaml code

```
<TextBox Name="textbox11" IsEnabled="False".....>
```

but obviously it doesnt work. The error I get :

```
'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Enabled' and no extension method 'Enabled' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The control doesn't have a property called "Enabled".  Try this:

```
textbox11.IsEnabled = true;
```

Note the "Is".

Comment: I thought I tried it already but I tried It again and it worked! woops! thank you very much! will accept answer .